# Method "animatedWithDuration( )" missing argument for parameter 'delay'

Tags: ios, animation, closures

In order to add a menu which looks like 'Passbook-Menu' in my Swift app, I found a proper demo, written in Objective-C, from Github. And I translated ObjC into Swift smoothly until I found two Blocks in the origin demo. And I got to know that Block is supposed to be translated into Closure after I checked some guide books.

I tried and I failed. Complier thrown the failure that "animatedWithDuration( ) missing argument for parameter 'delay' "

1. At the first, I need to claim that I did not select the method that animatedWithDuration() has the parameter 'delay'.
2. I not quite understand two sentences which were marked by many exclamation marks. "if (halfway) halfway(finished)" and "if (completion) completion(finished)"  Because the 'if' sentence always be written with only one '()', not two.
3. Please tell me where did I write the wrong things in my code.

A great appreciation for your time and your guide.

Ethan Joe

**The origin code:**

```
- (void)flipTransitionWithOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options halfway_1:(void (^)(BOOL finished))halfway completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
{
    CGFloat degree = (options & UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight) ? -M_PI_2 : M_PI_2;
```

```
CGFloat duration = 0.4;
CGFloat distanceZ = 2000;
CGFloat translationZ = self.frame.size.width / 2;
CGFloat scaleXY = (distanceZ - translationZ) / distanceZ;

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -distanceZ; // perspective
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 0, 0, translationZ);

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DScale(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, scaleXY, scaleXY, 1.0);
self.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration / 2 animations:^{
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, degree, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (halfway) halfway(finished); !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, -degree, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration / 2 animations:^{
        self.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        self.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        if (completion) completion(finished); !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }];
}];
```

**My copy-translated version:**

UIView.animateWithDuration(duration / 2, animations: {self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform, degree, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)}, completion: {(finshed) -> Void in
        if halfway(finished) {
            self.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform, -degree, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration / 2, animations: {self.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTrabsform}, completion: {(finished) -> Void in
                self.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
                if completion(finshed){}
            })
        }
    }
    )

}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `duration / 2` with `NSTimeInterval(duration / 2)`on the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer solved parameter problem. And another one coming.

Comment: Can you explain sentences with exclamation marks above I asked?  { if (halfway) halfway(finished); }

Comment: As you can see in the parameters `halfway`is a completion block (a kind of function) which take a boolean as parameter(here the finished boolean) and which have to be executed once the animation is finished (your expression is equivalent to  `{ if (halfway != nil) halfway(finished); } `).